# How would my web page examples look like before mod rewrite when using PHP

Tags: php, html, page-layout

I want to display all my tags on one web page for example, `www.example.com/tags/` and then when some one 
clicks on one of the tags I want to display all the posts related to that tag on another web page for example, `www.example.com/tags/clicked-tag/` 
how would I be able to do this since it really would not be a good idea to create a web page for each tag?

I will be creating an index.php page for the tags folder `www.example.com/tags/`.

But how would I be able to display the posts related to that tag on another page for example, `www.example.com/tags/clicked-tag/`?

Answer (score 1):

Mod_rewrite for generating get variable in "nice" form

You have to add mysql field called "tag" or something

Comment: but where would all tags post be display at?

Comment: You'll have to check if tag variable (f.e. isset($_GET['tag']) )exists, else display all.

Comment: so I would display all the tags on web page along with the clicked tags post and it will still give the web page layout I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use a rewrite rule. Create a PHP file named say "details.php" inside the tag folder.

Then, in httpd.conf:

```
RewriteRule /tags/([^/]+)/?$ /tags/details.php?tag=$1 [B,L]
```

or, if you must, in a .htaccess file inside /tags:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=details.php
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ details.php?tag=$1 [B]
```

Another possibility would be to activate the option `MultiViews` and serve all requests to `/tags/*`  from a file named `tags.php` in the root (using the path info to determine what to show).

Comment: @snag I assumed you were using Apache. If you are, it has [an extension](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) usually available that allows you to rewrite URLs.

Comment: I was just wondering how would my pages look like before rewrite is what I meant.

Comment: @snag Before rewrite they'll look the way you want. One a request to those URLs arrives the server internally rewrites them to `/tag/details.php` or whatever (the client doesn't see them).

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here? You seem to want to display all posts for a given tag `<my_tag>` on the page `www.example.com/tags/clicked-tag.php`?

So, can't your tags link to `www.example.com/tags/clicked-tag?tag=<tag_name>`, where `<tag_name>` is different for each tag, obviously, and then `www.example.com/tags/clicked-tag.php` simply look at a variable `$_GET["tag"]`?

That seems the way to do it in PHP, but since others are giving rewrite answers I fear that I may have misunderstood the question. If so, maybe you could clarify?

---

`i want all the tags to have their own unique file name like www.example.com/tags/tag1 www.example.com/tags/tag2 www.example.com/tags/tag3 and so on` - thanks for the clarification.

How about ... mmmm ... all links on the first page lead to an intermediate page which the user will never see ... `www.example.com/tags/clicked-tag.php` for example, and that does something like

```
   if file www.example.com/tags/<tag> not exists then crete it  
   header("Location: www.example.com/tags/<tag>");
```

and each  page includes a common file with a function which takes  as a paramater and build the output page ...

That would do it, wouldn't it?